# WPF ToggleButton does not want to apply style

Tags: c#, wpf, styles, datatrigger

My ToggleButton become "green" when "PauseUpdate" is false but otherwise it stay blue (like when the focus is on) althought I put the focus elsewhere. It never becomes red.

Also, my text is always "Pause", never "Paused". Why?

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="7" Padding="7" IsChecked="{Binding PauseUpdate}">
                        <TextBox Text="Pause" IsReadOnly="True" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseUpdate}" Value="true">
                                            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Paused" />
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>

                        </TextBox>

                        <ToggleButton.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity=".2"></SolidColorBrush>
                        </ToggleButton.Background>

                        <ToggleButton.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseUpdate}" Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Background">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity=".2"></SolidColorBrush>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>

                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseUpdate}" Value="false">
                                        <Setter Property="Background">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity=".2"></SolidColorBrush>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </ToggleButton.Style>
                    </ToggleButton>
                    
                    <TextBox Width="60"></TextBox>
                </StackPanel>
```

Comment: Try putting in a default `Setter`, outside of all the triggers, to make the color green and then get rid of the trigger for `PauseUpdate` being false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple points to be fixed:

1. `TextBox` consumes mouse events and thus prevents `ToggleButton` from responding to them. Moreover, it is just used to show a text. So `TextBlock` is  appropriate.
2. A local value prevails over the value set in Style and thus prevents Style.Triggers from changing actual value. So remove the local value and set the value in Style.
3. The `Background` when `IsChecked` is true is given by default ControlTemplate of  `ToggleButton`. To override it, set a plain ControlTemplate in `Template` of Style.

Then, the modified `ToggleButton` would be as follows:

```xml
<ToggleButton HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="7" Padding="7"
              IsChecked="{Binding PauseUpdate}">
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="Pause"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseUpdate}" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="Paused" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>

    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                        <Border x:Name="border"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              Focusable="False" RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseUpdate}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red" Opacity=".2"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PauseUpdate}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Background">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green" Opacity=".2"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much for the code but mainly for all the explanation.  I wonder how you determine exactly all the portion of the ControlTemplate? For me, it would have required many hours (perhaps days) before I would have figured out all that properly? Is it only experience?

Comment: You are welcome. Mainly from my experience as well as knowledge shared in SO.